# phpMyAdmin doesn't let me run more than one query at a time, and importing my SQL fails

Tags: mysql, sql, database, import, phpmyadmin

I have two large SQL files that I'm trying to import. I generated these SQL files by parsing out data from an old MySQL database's CSV export. If I try to import these into the new MySQL database, it takes a few minutes and eventually says that it passed. But when I look at the tables, none of the INSERT statements did anything to the tables.

If I run the statements in my SQL files one by one in the phpMyAdmin SQL window, they successfully insert records into the tables. So I tried to copy and paste the entire SQL files into window. It takes a while but eventually I get an Error code: 500.

How am I supposed to solve this issue? Connecting to the database is annoyingly stupid and frustrating since I don't know where to find all of the information about the database and since all the resources I've found so far tell me how to connect to a local database rather than one that is hosted elsewhere. I just want to import these SQL files and be done with it. I'm just trying to insert a bunch of things into two tables. Here's a sample of the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('base_fee_paid', 0)
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('featured_paid', 0)
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('private_bids_paid', 0)
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('do_not_require_shipping', 0)
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('featured', 1)
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('allow-offers', 0)
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('Location', 'California')
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('quant', 1)
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('buy_now', 130.0)
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('reserve', 0)
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('private_bids', 'no')
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('only_buy_now', 1)
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('auto_renew_item', 0)
```

That's from one of the SQL files. The other SQL file is similar but inserting some different data into a different table. If I run the INSERT statements up above one by one in the phpMyAdmin SQL window, they get inserted no problem. But if I try to import the entire file...it says that it was a success but when I look at the table, I don't see the changes. Thanks for any suggestions.

Note: The SQL block I just shared is just one block. For each product, we have a block like that. After that block is a space followed by another block. I included spaces so that I could more easily differentiate between the different products if I was looking at the SQL file. The bigger SQL file is around 100,000 lines. The other one is around 20,000 lines.

Comment: Phpmyadmin is not really suitable to import large files, since its execution time is restricted by php configuration - hence the errorcode 500. Do you have access to mysql's command line client on your server?

Comment: I don't currently have access but I can request it. Would chopping up my files into 10,000-line chunks be a better strategy?

Comment: Yes, that's also an option. But what happens, if you have to import a file with 1 million such statements?

Comment: Have you tried seperating commands by **;** like
`INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('only_buy_now', 1);
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('auto_renew_item', 0);`?

Comment: @Shadow May the universe have mercy on my soul. If I absolutely had to import a file like that, I'd hope they were hosting their database in a different environment of some kind. Surely this phpMyAdmin problem isn't universal?

Comment: @DanielWalter I haven't tried that but I can try it. Thanks for the suggestion, I hope it works.

Comment: @DanielWalter Yes, it worked for the first file! Now to try the larger one. :)

Comment: @DanielWalter Wow, it ran all 47,567 queries in a matter of seconds. That's insanely fast. Please share your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate commands by `;` like:

```
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ('only_buy_now', 1);
INSERT INTO b1b_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ('auto_renew_item', 0);
```

As I stated in comment [phpMyAdmin doesn't let me run more than one query at a time, and importing my SQL fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665654/phpmyadmin-doesnt-let-me-run-more-than-one-query-at-a-time-and-importing-my-sq?noredirect=1#comment55104638_33665654)