# How to do this as mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a mysql query. I have a table like this 
I have "type" 1 to 15. I would like help with a query to automatically change the "type"

Comment: What causes the points to go down (or up)?

Comment: when members perform certain activity on the site, the points go up and certain other activity makes the points to go down

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it as an update, because you're saying that points determine type, and you want points AND type in the table, which means they must always be kept in sync. Of the two, points is more fine grained - points can be used to determine type but not the other way round - so we can devise a strategy to determine the type from the current points, and we can let points increase and the type will change automatically upon querying:

make another table with the type, lower and upper bound for points and then join it in to find the type:

```
CREATE TABLE  TypeRanges (
  playerType INT,
  fromPoints INT,
  toPoints INT
)

INSERT INTO TypeRanges VALUES(1, 0, 1599)
...


SELECT * FROM 
  username p
  INNER JOIN typeRanges t ON p.points BETWEEN t.fromPoints AND t.toPoints
```

Remember that BETWEEN is inclusive at both ends so for < 1600 points you want the end to be 1599, for 1600 to 14000 you probably want 1600 and 13999 etc

If you want, you can make a view out of this query and then use that view anywhere you want to know the points and the type together. See the comments for a bit more on what a view is /used for

Footnote on dynamism/ performance considerations:

Every time you run this query it will calculate the type from the points. Calculating the type when you run the query rather than updating the type when the points change means you can easily redefine the bounds or add to them just by altering the points range table. Because we are calculating every time it's highly responsive to data updating but it would be a few nanoseconds slower than having type stored and retrieved simply; in most cases the benefits of recalculating outweigh this but if you're going to be querying it thousands of times per second and updating it once a year (as an extreme example) it may make sense to store the type instead. In most typical use cases I would go the route of calculating the type from the points and only look to optimize it if it proves to be a problem when scaled to large numbers of users and lots of activity. It would be a premature optimization to assume that lookup will make things unusably slow and seeking to store it - databases are engineered towards rapid data joining and retrieval. If you did determine that storing it would be better you can make the sync transparent by using a trigger to import the type upon each update

---

Side note; seek to avoid using [reserved/keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) like TYPE as column names - while they can be quoted etc it usually does more good to find a more descriptive label for the column that doesn't need to be quoted in queries and treated specially in front end languages

Comment: This is a better alternative than updating.

Comment: Excellent. Many thanks for the answer. Just 2 questions:

1) In the query, you mention player. In my case, as per the screen shot of the phpmyadmin (screen shot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwWdY.png), it should be the  "username", right?

2) By creating this table like you mentioned, would the operation be automatic? I mean any future users who fall between the point criteria, they will be auto synced with the type?

Comment: Oh, yes sorry - player is a typo - I got distracted by "points" meaning game/players etc - it's a bit harder on a cellphone to nip back up to the top of the question and click into an image without losing everything so I'd forgotten the name of the table

Comment: The operation of getting a username's type is automatic if you join these two tables every time you want to know the user with his points and his type. If you make it a VIEW with `create view usernamewithtype as (select...)` and then you later `select * from usernamewithtype` the db will re-run the query that the view is based on and thus get updated values but to many other intents and purposes, views look and behave like tables so creating a view can be a simple way to encapsulate this querying logic into a single entity like a table, that can be queried.

Comment: I just tried to create the table as you mentioned and i ran into the following error. screen shot https://i.postimg.cc/FHWQryJv/error.png

Comment: You probably need to put semicolons at the end of each statement if you're trying to execute them as one command - I'm not really sure how your query tool will split them up though; I've never used phpmyadmin to run multiple sql in a batch. I caution against the use of "type" as a column name

Comment: Multiple statements in phpmyadmin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665654/phpmyadmin-doesnt-let-me-run-more-than-one-query-at-a-time-and-importing-my-sq

Comment: Hi caius Jard, do you have an account in Fiverr? Can you please do this for me in phpmyadmin if I pay you via Fiverr gig? Many thanks.

Comment: Ha, I don't have an account but I'm happy to do it for free on SO. Edit your question and paste your phpmyadmin window text I to your question (not a screenshot; I can't copy text out of a screenshot) and I'll do it on some fiddle site. Have you tried running the statements one at a time in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy storing your logic in the table itself, then you could use a calculated column.

```
CREATE TABLE members (
 points INT, 
 type DOUBLE AS 
   (CASE 
     WHEN points < 1600 THEN 1
     WHEN points < 14000 THEN 2
     -- TODO: implement other cases
     ELSE 3 
    END))
```

So when the points column is updated, there is no need to "update" the type column - the type is automatically calculated from the points whenever the table is read.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fqEL2jtNio1Srt5xLkyLy2/0

Edit:

As Caius Jard mentions in their answer, the performance of selects would start to degrade at scale, but how you optimize depends on how volatile the points are, and how frequent your reads are.